# Suggested improvements to badges index page

Tags: badges, feature-request

**([Migrated from UserVoice](http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/220131-improvements-to-badge-index-page?direct_login_token=0f0ab78c1602769f6c55735e05fc446d&subdomain=stackoverflow&tracking_code=ef3bbd3827bfb469bfe755d535125b10))**

Currently, https://stackoverflow.com/badges shows the possible badges, number of total recipients, and brief descriptions. However, I have a few suggestions (mostly minor changes) that could make it a bit nicer.

- There is no way to see (on that page) which badges I've earned multiple times — they all appear with a green checkmark. It would be nice to show something like "x 4" like in the badges section of the user profile page. For example:

[image]

- There is no way to see which badges **can** be awarded multiple times — you have to click on a specific badge to see yea or nay. It would be nice to have a small, simple icon next to badges that can be earned multiple times, similar to the checkmark showing which badges I've earned.
- The layout would be nicer if the number of recipients for each badge were in a separate column — since the badge images are different sizes, the overlap and ragged right alignment makes the numbers harder to read.
- An alternative view that groups badges by "achievement level" (gold/silver/bronze) would be nice, as would a view that groups progressive degrees of the same accomplishment. (e.g. Nice Answer → Good Answer → Great Answer **OR** Popular Question → Notable Question → Famous Question)

Comment: the last part of your request is implemented

Comment: The third part of your request is implemented

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the look of the badges site. I think it would be much nicer if they would group the badges by type (gold, silver, bronze) and show visually what badge can or cant be awarded multiple times.

Comment: Stop answering things faster than me!

Comment: No                 .

Comment: Umm, I did mention that. "It would be nice to show something like "x4" like in the badges section of the user profile page." Maybe everyone was rushing through reading so they could answer first. :-)

Comment: Since it's the same sentence it reads like you are suggesting it to be in the badges section. Adding an is would make it clearer "like "4x" like is in the badges section"

Comment: It appears in the badges section *of the user profile page*. I'd like the count to also appear on http://stackoverflow.com/badges when I'm logged it. Currently I get a checkmark next to every badge I've earned 1+ times.

Comment: I get your point, and i agree, i just misread it since you're not splitting the sentence up to know where the focus is.