# Please tidy how badges are displayed

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested improvements to badges index page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page)

Cosmetic issue... is it possible to improve the **display of badges on the profile page**? An [obvious example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet):

[Jon Skeet badges http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/tags.png](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/tags.png)

**Suggested improvements:**

- Split out tag-based badges into a separate section
- Sort by alphabetical order

Comment: Sort by length, to form nice wedge-shaped columns. The artistically-inclined among us will be ecstatic! :)

Comment: [link](http://alexangas.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/08/tags.png) is dead :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would prefer that they get sorted in two methods:

- Sort by badge types (Gold, Silver, Bronze). You could also in theory have a section specifically for the gold and silver tag badges.
- Sort alphabetically per badge group. This way all of the golds are in alphabetical, all the silvers are in alphabetical, etc. etc.
- Optional sorting by number of badges won so that you can get a quick view of your most "hit" badges.

Answer (score 4):

They're sorted in the order they are achieved. I like that sort, and don't you try to take that away from me. Haven't you taken enough?!

Also, they belong on the stats tab. They are your stats, and they are glorious. If anything, I'd put them above the Tags section.

Comment: Ha ha! Although sorting by achievement means a lot less when you have multiple badges of the same type

Comment: They should be the only thing displaying when you click on a user name.