# Badges to be displayed category-wise

Tags: feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please tidy how badges are displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/please-tidy-how-badges-are-displayed)

SO should display badges categorically. It looks cluttered when all the badges are displayed together. Categories could be 'questions' , 'answers' , 'editing' etc.

Your comments.

Comment: There's probably a Greasemonkey script for it

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16040/please-tidy-how-badges-are-displayed