# Sorting of badges

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badges, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suggested improvements to badges index page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page)

Answers and questions can be sorted by different types (votes, newest, views, recent).
At the same time badges are automatically sorted only by the date, a person earned it.

Besides "standard" badges (I mean Altruist, Analytical, Announcer etc.), there are "upvote" badges, which can be earned, when you get 100, 400 and 1000 upvotes for some tag.

And when you have a big number of badges of different types, it looks messy. Maybe, some sort options should be added?

As for me, there must be at least 2 options:

1. by time when earned;
2. by type of badge (bronze, silver, gold) + by alphabet; and
   "standard" and "upvote" badges could be shown separately.

What do you think?

Comment: "And when you have a big number of badges of different types, it looks messy" You mean, like [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/)?

Comment: OMG! Exactly :)

Comment: Which one sort options would _you_ like to see?

Comment: @bad How about [sort by Tower](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63745/badges-should-be-ordered-alphabetically/63816#63816)?

Comment: @PopularDemand: the other question is about features for the badges overview (potential badges), this question is about earned badges (part of your profile). Looks like this is either `status-completed` or "did you click on the 'badges' tab and try sorting; the feature is there!" depending on when acquired badge sorting was implemented.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you're right, this is __not__ a dupe of "Suggested improvements to badges index page." Might be Too Localized now, though the new profile page wasn't rolled out until two months after this was asked.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Marking this as `[status-completed]` would suffice too, no?

Comment: @MartijnPieters yep. In a way, 90% of things that are completed are too localized, because further answers would be pointless. That always kind of bothered me about metas.