# Add links to related badges on a badge's page

Tags: feature-request, badges

For example the [Nice Question Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/20/nice-question) page, could have links to the [Good Question Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/21/good-question) page and the [Great Question Badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/22/great-question) page.

This would provide a little better navigation when researching available badges.

EDIT:
Other related Meta questions:

- [Suggested improvements to badges index page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page)

Comment: We have a design update for the badges page on the books (no timeline yet, we've been *very* busy).  We'll definitely put this idea in the hopper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this system to match similar tags should work:

- Every badge should have hidden tags
- There should be a *Similar tags:* (or *See also:*) list containing every badge that have one of the tags from the currently viewing badge

The tag/badge list should be something like:

```
==Bounties
Investor    First bounty you offered on another person's question
Altruist    First bounty you manually awarded on another person's question
Promoter    First bounty you offered on your own question
Benefactor  First bounty you manually awarded on your own question

==Visits
Analytical      Visited every section of the FAQ
Enthusiast      Visited the site each day for 30 consecutive days
Fanatic         Visited the site each day for 100 consecutive days
Announcer       Shared a link to a question that was visited by 25 unique IP addresses
Booster         Shared a link to a question that was visited by 300 unique IP addresses
Publicist       Shared a link to a question that was visited by 1000 unique IP addresses

==Flaggs
Citizen Patrol      First flagged post
Deputy              Raised 80 helpful flags
Marshal             Raised 500 helpful flags

==Votes
Supporter       First up vote
Critic          First down vote
Suffrage        Used 30 votes in a day
Vox Populi      Used the maximum 40 votes in a day
Sportsmanship   Up voted 100 answers on questions where an answer of yours has a positive score
Civic Duty      Voted 300 or more times
Electorate      Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

==Comments
Commentator     Left 10 comments
Pundit          Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more
Talkative       Posted 10 messages, with 1 or more starred, in chat
Outspoken       Posted 10 messages in chat that were starred by 10 different users

==Questions
Student             Asked first question with score of 1 or more
Scholar             Asked a question and accepted an answer
Nice Question       Question score of 10 or more
Good Question       Question score of 25 or more
Great Question      Question score of 100 or more

==Questions + Favorites
Favorite Question       Question favorited by 25 users
Stellar Question        Question favorited by 100 users

==Questions + Views
Tumbleweed              Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week
Popular Question        Asked a question with 1,000 views
Notable Question        Asked a question with 2,500 views
Famous Question         Asked a question with 10,000 views

==Answers
Nice Answer     Answer score of 10 or more
Good Answer     Answer score of 25 or more
Great Answer    Answer score of 100 or more
Teacher         Answered first question with score of 1 or more
Self-Learner    Answered your own question with score of 3 or more
Enlightened     First to answer and accepted with at least 10 upvotes
Generalist      Provided non-wiki answers of 15 total score in 20 of top 40 tags
Reversal        Provided answer of +20 score to a question of -5 score
Tenacious       Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total
Unsung Hero     Zero score accepted answers: more than 10 and 25% of total
Revival         Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more
Necromancer     Answered a question more than 60 days later with score of 5 or more
Populist        Highest scoring answer that outscored an accepted answer with score of more than 10 by more than 2x

==Reputation
Yearling        Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation
Mortarboard     Earned at least 200 reputation in a single day
Epic            Earned 200 daily reputation 50 times
Legendary       Earned 200 daily reputation 150 times

==Tags
Organizer       First retag
Synonymizer     First approved tag synonym
Tag Editor      First Tag Wiki Edit
Taxonomist      Created a tag used by 50 questions

==Tags + Edits
Research Assistant      Edited 50 tag wikis

==Edits
Editor              First edit
Cleanup             First rollback
Strunk & White      Edited 80 posts
Archaeologist       Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months
Copy Editor         Edited 500 posts
Excavator           Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months
Proofreader         Approved or rejected 100 suggested edits

==Accepts
Guru            Accepted answer and score of 40 or more

==Deletes
Peer Pressure       Deleted own post with score of -3 or lower
Disciplined         Deleted own post with score of 3 or higher

==Miscellaneous
Autobiographer      Completed all user profile fields
Precognitive        Followed the Area 51 proposal for this site before it entered the commitment phase
Reviewer            1000 reviews, over 200 actioned
```

In addition to a new tag **First** for the badges that are about the *First X* (excluding the *Enlightened* badge)

---

Here is an example of how the linking works:

> In the case of **Research Assistant** (tags: *Tags* + *Edits*), the
>   suggested list should contain some (or all?) badges from the badges
>   tagged as *Tags* and *Edits*

Answer (score 4):

I think it is a good idea. Together with some more, deeper explanation. Some badges are clear but others are a bit difficult to understand. It is true that a bit more navigation would be nice.

Also a link to the "badge status" to see your progress.