# Add number of badges earned on Badges page

Tags: feature-request, badges

You can already see the number of a specific badge you've earned on your own profile page. I'd also like to propose that we add that number to the main [Badges](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) page in one of the two fashions shown below.

Exactly like on the profile page:

[image]

Slight variation:

[image]

I tend to click on Badges any time I want a quick glance at what I have, so it would be nice to add this information here as well. Should be fairly simple to implement.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1980/suggested-improvements-to-badges-index-page?rq=1

Comment: Nice find, I didn't see that in my searching.

Comment: Do note that you can edit that duplicate question, updating it with some snazzy screenshots. That would bring it attention and upvotes, in addition to making it easier to salivate and visualize the improvements.